# What if I made a mistake in a paper and now I got a minor revision?

Tags: publications, research-process, writing, databases, machine-learning

I have received a minor revision after a major revision for a paper.

I discovered that I made a mistake in the calculations. Fixing it will result in changing a lot of the results, but the final result will not change much.

So should I mention these changes to the reviewers (they are noticable) or should I just correct the mistake without mentioning it to the reviewers in the response?

Answer (score 66):

You should **always** mention this! If you don't, then the entire manuscript becomes suspect. The reviewer has no way of telling what else you changed, and would be forced to recheck the entire manuscript. It's very time-consuming (and cruel of the authors).

Tell the reviewers *exactly* where your revisions are and why you're making them. You're already using their time, try to make their work as simple as possible.

Comment: Hijacking this great answer to add that something you can do to be *kind* to the referee (at least, in the journals in physics I am familiar with) is to make your revisions to the text in color, so the reviewer can quickly see what has changed. (The final page proofs will remove this color).

Comment: We usually also include a "changelog", addressing each of the referee's comments:

*Referee comment 1* We added a new paragraph in section 1.2.3 to address this.
*Referee comment 2* This is not valid because ....
*Referee comment 3* We fixed this error, affecting equations 1, 2, and 3
*Other changes* Apart from the comments by the referee we also fixed errors in equations 7, 8, and 9. They do not affect the final result

Comment: Excuse the formatting above, apparently a lot of markdown is not supported in comments?

Comment: @Simon Yeah, each comment is forced to display as a single paragraph, so only inline formatting is supported; no line breaks, paragraphs, bullet lists, etc.

Comment: @Andrew I sometimes use latexdiff, so the reviewers get a final document and the exact list of what was changed.

Answer (score 9):

Been there, done that. You need to redo the calculations and rewrite the paper. Make sure you communicate your needs to the handling editor. They will decide if it needs to go back to the reviewers.